# How to compute the $AS$ where $A$ is a matrix and $S$ is a sphere

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S = \{ (x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n : x_1^2 + \cdots x_n^2 =  1 \}$. Let $A$ be an $m \times n $ matrix and say $m \geq n$. How can we compute $AS$. Is there an algorithm to compute such product? This is what I Think:

By $AS$, are we multiplying a vector in $S$ with the matrix $A$? If so, then we know $AS $ is again a $1 \times n$ column matrix. So for example, if $n = 2 $ and we take $A = ( [1,2],[2,3] )$ where $[\cdot,\cdot]$ is a row. Then $AS = A (x,y)^T = (x + 2y, 2x+3y)^T $. Is this correct?

Comment: What object are you expecting $AS$ to be ? A matrix??

Comment: That is what I dont understand. What does the meaning of this object? is it a vector ?

Comment: Where did you come across this notation $AS$? It's not very traditional to have the notation $matrix \times point set$, so you'll probably have to look at the source where you found it and see if they give additional details. One possibility that comes to my mind is that $AS = \{p \in \mathbb{R}^n : p =As, s \in S \}$.